# Which journals should I read to keep up on advances in solving PDEs numerically?

Tags: pde, publications

I solve a lot of PDEs numerically, but applied math isn't my field. I haven't picked up on which applied math journals I should read to keep up with recent developments in the field.

What are good journals to read to keep up with recent developments in solving PDEs numerically?

Comment: This might be a good candidate for a community wiki question.

Comment: I think the answer to your question was accidentally placed here:  "http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1115/is-a-checkerboard-block-decomposition-of-a-matrix-useful-when-solving-a-linear-s".

Comment: @David Ketcheson: That might be a good idea.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: There's been a discussion about Community Wiki on Meta [here](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/162/a-thread-to-request-questions-be-made-community-wiki/163#comment235_163), and the question is shaping up to be a list question, although it's sort of borderline. For now, I'm closing it, even though it's on-topic, because it's not a good fit for the format and I don't think wikifying it fixes that problem.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: Reopened again.

Answer (score 11):

In no particular order, I'll add more as I think of them.

- SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing
- Journal of Scientific Computing
- Journal of Computational Physics
- Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering
- International Journal of Numerical Methods in Engineering
- AIAA conference proceedings
- Transactions on Mathematical Software
- Computers and Structures
- Acta Numerica
- Numerische Mathematik
- SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis
- Mathematics of Computation

Also, many application-specific journals have papers on computational methods. It is definitely worth watching appropriate sections of the arXiv.

Before Google Reader killed sharing, we had a group of about 30 people that would monitor different journals and share relevant papers to discuss. We are now, begrudgingly, using Google+ and Reddit for that purpose.

Comment: Jed, could you edit your question to add more details about the journals? See some of the thoughts I've sketched out [here](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/166/are-questions-about-lists-of-journals-allowed). I've asked DavidKetcheson to do the same, and I think it's turned out well so far.

Answer (score 9):

A listing of all journals that publish papers on numerical solution of PDEs would be quite long, and it would be impossible for any one person to keep up with the entirety of the subject.  But if you want to stick to journals that

- Are highly regarded
- Include fairly general classes of PDEs (as opposed to only PDEs in some scientific field)

then I would suggest starting with

- [**SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing (SISC)**](http://www.siam.org/journals/sisc.php): This one traditionally was focused entirely on new algorithms, but has [recently branched out to include software or application-oriented papers](http://www.siam.org/journals/sisc/redefined.php).  It targets more of an applied math community.  Usually somewhat slower turnaround time.  Lower acceptance rate (~50%).
- [**Journal of Computational Physics**](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-computational-physics/): This includes a lot of applications papers and a lot of algorithms papers; it's more applied than SISC.  Publishes a huge volume of articles (relatively speaking).  While it is still very highly regarded, and many consider it "the place" to publish numerical PDEs papers, some (myself included) feel that the quality has slipped in recent years.  This may accelerate if the Elsevier boycott takes off.
- [**Journal of Scientific Computing**](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/computational+science+&+engineering/journal/10915): Relatively similar to SISC in most respects.  I think the turnaround time for reviewing may be a bit faster and the "prestigiousness" may be a bit lower.

An easy way to keep up with new articles is to subscribe to the journal's RSS feed.  You should also definitely subscribe to the [math.NA](http://arxiv.org/list/math.NA/recent) feed on arXiv.

I spend most of my time figuring out how to numerically solve PDEs; you can find a longer list of journals I follow [on my blog](http://scienceinthesands.blogspot.com/2011/10/you-are-what-you-read-journals-i-follow.html).